# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of '_Printer' and 'int'. Can't figure out what it means

Tags: python

I am beginning to learn python and doing a practice program.

I've inserted the code below.

```
av_grade = int(input ("What is your average grade? "))

if(av_grade >= 70):
  absences = int(input ("How many absences do you have? "))
  if (absences <= 5):
    credits = int(input ("How many credits have you earned? "))
  else: 
    print("You are not eligible for privileges")
    if (credits >= 17):
      print("You are eligible for senior privileges")
    elif (credits >= 11):
      print("You are eligible for junior privileges")
    else:
      print("You are not eligible for privileges")
else:
  print("You are not eligible for privileges")
```

Looking for any help if possible about what I can do to fix this.

Comment: Please include in the question what input you're providing to the program, and the full error message including the stack trace - see [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing the variable credits before you set it to a value and credits is a built in variable:

```
C:\Temp>test.py
What is your average grade? 89
How many absences do you have? 9
You are not eligible for privileges
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    if (credits >= 17):
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of '_Printer' and 'int'


C:\Temp>python
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:04:37) [MSC v.1929 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> type(credits)
<class '_sitebuiltins._Printer'>
>>>
```

If absences > 5 then you access credits before you set it.

Bobby